# Pairing bluetooth input device does not work

Tags: 10.10, bluetooth

I try to get my Bluetooth keyboard 'KeySonic ACK-540BT' working. Everytime i try to pair it with my computer (Ubuntu 10.10), it fails. The numbers which i have to type are never accepted.

The keyboard is visible in BlueMan GUI and i got my TRUST BT-Mouse working.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out! (this is written with the bluetooth keyboard)

1. press the pairing-button on the backside of the keyboard
2. Do a search within your bluetooth devices (blueman gui)
3. right-click on the keyboard (also in blueman gui) -> pairing
4. type in 4 numbers with your USB keyboard and press enter
5. type in the same numbers with your bluetooth keyboard and press enter

This should pair the keyboard. After this you have to connect the keyboard service

1. right-click on the keyboard (also in blueman gui) -> settings
2. connect the service!

Finally you should have your keyboard working!